# Algorithm or java code for searching patterns in matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I have a 4 * 5 matrix like the one below.

```
1 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1
```

I am looking for a program in java to get a pattern of the following groups.

- A group of subsequent 5 1s.
- A group of subsequent 2 1s.
- 2 groups of single 1s.

And none of the above groups should intersect. 
This was an interview question at Zycus infotech which I couldn't solve. Anyone who can suggest the logic to solving this, would be great help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make the assumption that there was no restrictions on what you could do with the data and organizing it. By this I mean you didn't have to do everything in-place with the given matrix and that you could make helper data structures to assist you in the task (as I used an additional ArrayList in my answer).

We are starting with:

```
int[][] matrix = {{1,1,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1},{1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1}};
```

to correspond to our original structure of:

```
1 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1
```

So, we see right off the bat that in order to get a group of 4 1's we need to go wrap from line 2 to line 3, and then to get a group of 5 1's we need to wrap from line 4 back around to line 1. This means that we're basically looking at this matrix as one continuous line of 1's and 0's and the matrix structure makes this confusing. So we can flatten this to make things a bit easier:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            list.add(matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

and this gives us:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

and this looks a bit nicer already! However, we still have the issue of this list wrapping around itself in a cycle. Now, we could write code to account for this list wrapping around on itself still for possible adjacent 1's, or we could just modify the list such that we know 100% for sure there are no adjacent 1's between the start and end of the list. This means we want the list to either start or end with a 0, thus ensuring no adjacency. We accomplish this with a nice little shift of all 1's from the start of the list to the end of the list.

```
    // keep track of how we're adjusting the list so we can calculate the proper start of adjacency
    int adjustment = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == 1) {
            list.add(list.remove(i));
            i--;
            adjustment++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

and now we have:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

which we can see is now very easy to get the desired groups of 1's as requested.

If you just wanted to count the adjacency of 1's:

```
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer a : list) {
        if (a == 1) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > 0) {
                System.out.println("Group of " + count + " adjacent 1's");
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.println("Group of " + count + " adjacent 1's");
    }
```

If you were looking for 1 group of 5 adjacent 1's, 2 groups of 2 adjacent 1's and 1 group of 1 adjacent 1 without intersection, then we could do:

```
    for (int num : Arrays.asList(5, 2, 2, 1)) {
        int count = 0;
        int start = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) == 1) {
                if (start == -1) {
                    start = i;
                }
                count++;
            } else {
                start = -1;
                count = 0;
            }
            if (count == num) {
                System.out.println("Group of " + num + " adjacent 1's starting at " + ((start + adjustment) / 5) + "," + ((start + adjustment) % 5));
                for (int j = start; j < start + count; j++) {
                    list.set(j, 0);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

which works by looking through the list counting adjacent ones till we hit our desired count (starting at our largest number (5) and working our way down smaller), then we output the start of it, then get rid of those adjacent 1's from our list (by setting them to 0). This way, we can't accidentally count them again (satisfying our restriction on no intersections of the groups). Once we get the desired count of adjacent 1's, we also store the starting position of that. We then adjust it based on how many 1's we moved from the start of the list to the back, and then divide to get row number and use modulo to get column number.

We get as our result:

```
Group of 5 adjacent 1's starting at 3,3
Group of 2 adjacent 1's starting at 1,4
Group of 2 adjacent 1's starting at 2,1
Group of 1 adjacent 1's starting at 1,0
```

So far I've made the assumption that the matrix will always have at least one 0 in it. If it doesn't, you need to add a check on `list.contains(0)` before my loop to move the 1's from the front of the list to the back of the list.

---

Putting this all together into one block of code:

```
    int[][] matrix = {{1,1,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1},{1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,1}};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            list.add(matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int adjustment = 0;
    if (list.contains(0)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) == 1) {
                list.add(list.remove(i));
                i--;
                adjustment++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (Integer a : list) {
        if (a == 1) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > 0) {
                System.out.println("Group of " + count + " adjacent 1's");
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.println("Group of " + count + " adjacent 1's");
    }

    for (int num : Arrays.asList(5, 2, 2, 1)) {
        int count2 = 0;
        int start = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) == 1) {
                if (start == -1) {
                    start = i;
                }
                count2++;
            } else {
                start = -1;
                count2 = 0;
            }
            if (count2 == num) {
                System.out.println("Group of " + num + " adjacent 1's starting at " + ((start + adjustment) / 5) + "," + ((start + adjustment) % 5));
                for (int j = start; j < start + count2; j++) {
                    list.set(j, 0);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, I understand the question by reading your answer *(assuming you've interpreted it correct)*. It should be the other way around. OP should add the expected output.

Comment: Thanks! This simplified things for me.